# basic Time and Date manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a time stamp of the in following form

```
2013-05-05 16:00:00
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the time part and advance it one day using javascript, so I have.

```
2013-05-06
```

Comment: wwhat have you tried? An internet search is an amazing thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date1 = new Date("2013-05-06 16:00:00");

var date2 = new Date(date1.getFullYear(),date1.getMonth(),date1.getDate()+1)
```

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer.  The date constructor will properly take a day like 32 in the third parameter, and increment the date to the first of the next month.

Answer (score 1):

Ok well make the time stamp a string and use the `.split()` method on the space that separates the date and time take a look here for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Or more appropriately use the requisite  date function like `new Date(year,month,day);` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp